# How do I send myself a message on Facebook using python?

Tags: python, facebook, bots

It appears `pyfacebook` and `simplefacebook` are deprecated. So is the facebook e-mail service. What is the current way of accomplishing this?

Comment: The [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) is the new black.  [This library](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: you don't need any of those

Comment: Private messages can not be send via API. All you can do is call the [Send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog), that allows the user to type a message himself and send it via explicit interaction.

Comment: have you tried the SendKeys module?

Comment: There currently is no documented API to do this. You could reverse the protocol Facebook uses internally for `messenger.com` and build a conform client in Python. However, an undocumented API can change any second, so you can't really rely on it.

Comment: Can't XMPP be used for this?

Comment: I thought Facebook is using Websockets/MQTT

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.facebook.com/products/messenger/

There appears to be links to build apps integrating messenger support here.

You can try to utilize the APIs there, since several apps seem integrated using it, I assume it is unlikely to change drastically anytime soon.

Here is a link I found which demonstrates the API for how to send messages using facebook's send API 
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog 
 The tutorial is for Javascript but you might be able to adapt it to work for Python as well.

Here's the build for an app called Facebook Autoresponder, you might be able to reverse engineer their process from looking at it : 
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-autoresponder/files/?source=navbar